# Why can an unprivileged user execute the `sync` command?

Tags: hard-disk, synchronization, privileges, authorization

Currently on Ubuntu Linux, but I noticed this on other OSs too. Apparently any user can execute the `sync` command – but why is this? I can only see the disadvantage: system slow down due to unnecessary disk writes.

Why can every user execute `sync`?

Comment: My question on this topic would be: Is there even a way to prevent users from using sync()?

Comment: @BonsiScott Sure, you can remove the permission bits from the executable. But I don't know if something will get broken when you do that.

Comment: Not only can any user run sync, you also don't need an account. The account 'sync' runs `/bin/sync` as its shell, so you can sync without logging in.

Comment: What is that useful for? BTW there is no password on the sync account on the box I am currently working on, so that won't work.

Comment: It is recommended for production systems to lower the wait-time between `sync`-calls (e.g. on HP-Unix). The reason is to avoid unnecessary waits due to masses of outstanding writes being written to disk all at once.

Answer (score 18):

There are plenty of ways for an unprivileged user to slow down a system and running sync is far from being the more efficient. On the other hand, having the file systems data committed to disk is quite a legitimate request so forbidding users (and thus their processes) to do it would be excessive.

In any case, I disagree about your "unnecessary disk writes" statement. These writes are certainly necessary and will automatically happen after a small period of time anyway.

There is even no guarantee the sync call will do anything particular at all depending on its implementation. Calling sync, is, [as the POSIX standard defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), only a "suggestion" for the OS to flush its file system caches, it doesn't necessarily force the flushes to happen immediately. More precisely, the calls ask the OS to schedule a cache flush but there is no guarantee it will happen before the already scheduled time although Linux implementation does wait for it to happen before returning.

Moreover, calling sync multiple times in a row would not slow down systems that much, as once the caches are flushed, if no process is actively writing to files the caches are empty so sync is a no-op.

Should you really want to prevent users to run sync on your system, you can just run these commands:

```
mv /bin/sync /bin/.sync
ln /bin/true /bin/sync
```

That would largely be unnoticed by users and has no negative effects except with people that just run sync then remove storage devices (eg: usb thumbdrive) without unmounting them, but these users were already acting foolishly anyway.

Note that I wouldn't recommend the previous /bin/sync link with /bin/true. `sync` is certainly useful in some cases. For example if you fear a brutal shutdown (power shortage, system panic, ...) might happen shortly, that would help preserving the file systems content. This is what I call a legitimate request.

Comment: If they happen automatically, what is the use for manually triggering it? If committing disk writes at user request is so important, why doesn't Windows have a button for it? (Yes I know I'm on a Unix stack here, but we are talking low level committing disk writes and Windows would have a similar issue).

Comment: Also I am talking about the `/bin/sync` command that can be interactively typed from the shell, not a `sync()` in eg. an `sqlight3` executable.

Comment: @jippie All the `sync` binary does is call the `sync()` function, so (like Bonsi Scott said) what you're really asking is why the kernel lets unprivileged users call `sync()`

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Not sure, maybe I'm asking why there is a `/bin/sync` binary. At least I think it doesn't have to be this easy to execute a sync. Either include it into eg. your database engine (like sqlite3 does) or if it is really important make it available to root only (or a group).

Comment: The sync(1) command is just a simple wrapper to the sync(2) system call. If the system call is allowed for a non root user, you cannot prevent the sync(1) command to be (re)implemented. There is no valid reason to forbid a user to ask for the data to be flushed to the disk immediately instead of waiting for the next system generated automatic flush. The OS is perfectly allowed not to immediately flush the data. Microsoft is free not to implement this functionality, just like an Unix compliant OS is free not to do anything when a user call sync. This is a non issue.

Comment: @jippie I think you're missing the point.  All sync ever does is commit (immediately) to disk things that were going to have to be committed anyway.  When I go to remove a flash drive, I want to make sure that everything I wrote to it actually got written.  And, while umount is supposed to guarantee this, I'm not assured, so I want (as a user) to make sure before I yank it.  There is NO HARM WHATSOEVER in forcing the system to flush buffers to disk.  At worst, some things are lagged for a second while the system actively flushes the buffers. The hazard would be in denying users this function.

Comment: @jippie Additionally:  Microsoft skipping the inclusion of a necessary function is... nothing new, and not surprising.

Comment: @killermist: sync is not forcing, just suggesting. Sync might return with a success exit status without having flushed anything to the disk, not to mention the disk itself might also delay writes under the hood. While I generally share the opinion Windows is missing necessary features, a sync command would the least of my concerns.

Comment: @killermist If you can't trust `umount` to flush the buffers to disk, why would you trust `sync`? Or should we start typing `sync; sync` like we are used on AIX?

Comment: @killermist @jippie is correct. You should better trust `umount`, which, whatever the OS, always flushes the buffers (unless the disk is gone ...) instead of `sync` which isn't guaranteed to do it depending on the OS. Note that Linux `sync` waits for the flush to be effective so can be trusted too.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync -> According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), sync() schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is done. However, since version 1.3.20 Linux does actually wait. (This still does not guarantee data integrity: modern disks have large caches.)

Comment: And, when you're in fear with Power outages and such, isn't mounting with -o sync not the best choise? (Apart from adding an UPS, of course)

Comment: If you are in fear of random power outages, that might be a poor man's "solution" indeed. My last note was more about a predictable risk, like a storm coming and flashes getting closer.

Comment: @jlliagre I think your "not forcing, just suggesting" point is enlightening and could be edited into your answer.

Answer (score 6):

`sync` cannot do any harm to the system. It can slow it down, but not more so than running programs that access the disk. Why should it be restricted?

There is a good reason to allow any user to run `sync`. This is necessary if some operations must be performed in order even if the system crashes or loses power. For example, consider a mail transfer agent which receives an email. Once it has written the file containing the email into the spool, it calls `sync`, and only then does it reply to the sending machine notifying it that the email has been received. If it didn't call `sync`, and the receiving machine lost power just after sending the reception notification but before committing the file to disk, then the email would be lost.

Operating systems delay disk writes for efficiency. They cannot know when an application really needs the write to happen. So applications are given a way to tell the operating system to write now, with [`sync(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sync) and [`sync(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sync.html) and [`fsync(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fsync.html).