# Calling sync without root privileges

Tags: sudo, cache, synchronization

I can call `sync` without root privileges. Does it flush all buffers to disk? Is it the same as calling it with root privileges like `sudo sync`?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57336

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

```
sync
```

called with no arguments will cause all dirty buffers to be flushed to disk, regardless of the identity of the user running it.

This is also true of the other modes some implementations of `sync` support, although in file-based cases other limitations apply — the user running `sync` has to be able to open the file being synced.

See [Why can an unprivileged user execute the `sync` command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57336/86440) for a discussion of the security aspects of this behaviour.